# Correctly display react-datepicker control

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox, react-datepicker

I am trying to use the 'react-datepicker' component, but it is being displayed correctly. Specifically, it has a one row height.[image]

Believe that the CSS is imported correct. I did:

```
import DatePicker from 'react-datepicker';
import 'react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css';
```

I am able to see that [some] `react-datepicker` styles are indeed imported. I just cannot figure out why my "popper" is displayed in a single line.

I used the component as:

```
    <div className="date-picker">
      <DatePicker 
      onChange={() => {}}
      selected={startDate}
    />
```

Please advise. If I add `flex-direction: column;` to `react-datepicker__month`, `react-datepicker__month-container` and `react-datepicker__header`, the problem goes away.

Comment: add your full component code with css and let me know.

Comment: Is their any CSS styles making it go on one row? Please check with inspect

Answer (score 0):

You should use a relative path instead of the absolute path.

You can import the `date-picker` CSS file from `node_modules`:

```js
import like 
import '../node_modules/react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css';
```